# From list of strings find strings with characters and combination of character + number

Tags: php

I have different types of string but I want to show only those string which is only characters or characters with digits.

```
$string = "abcxy";
$string1 = "abcxy12";
$string2 = "74.1234567,10.234";
$string3 = "100234";

if (ctype_digit($string)) {           
        echo "Yes\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "No\n"; 
    }
```

This doesn't work for string1 and string2.

Comment: Does `10.234` qualify as characters with digits, given that it has a decimal point?

Comment: No, 10.234 should be considered as numbers

Comment: Sorry, 1 more question, does comma `,` disqualify an input string?

Comment: yes, if there is comma it should say consider string as numbers. Sorry but this is very specific requirement for the string that are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP method `ctype_digit` checks for numeric character(s). See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) for details about this method.

For your special need, you might want to use some regex like below:

regex for alphabets and numbers (character with digits) - `/((?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[A-Za-z\d]*)/`

regex for characters - `/^[A-Za-z]+$/`

Combining these two:

```
function validateCharactersOrCharactersWithDigits ($string){
      return preg_match ('/((?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[A-Za-z\d]*)/' , $string) ||  
         preg_match ( '/^[A-Za-z]+$/' , $string);

}
```

Please check if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly fine and just to know that `ctype_digit()` function checks for all the chars as numeric so `,` in string result the function to return `false`.

```
<?php
$result = ["abcxy","abcxy12","74.1234567,10.234","100234"];

foreach ($result as $value) {
  if (ctype_digit($value)) {           
        echo "Yes\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "No\n"; 
    } 
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
No
No
No
Yes
```